# Oracle Performance on columns joining Non Unique Index col with Unique Index col

Tags: performance, indexing, oracle11g, left-join, inner-join

I am having a query like as shown below:

`select a.a1, a.a2, c.c1 
from a inner join b 
on a.nonUniqueIndexCol = b.uniqueIndexCol1
left outer join c
on c.nonUniqueIndexCol = b.uniqueIndexCol2`

Are the joins going to suffer from performance hit since we have non unique index and unique index are connected through equality? I don't have the explain plan.

Comment: No, that is what happens every time you join a foreign key column in a child table to the primary key of a parent table.

Comment: Performance hit compared to what?  a unique to a unique?  of COURSE!  but as @TonyAndrews points out it's expected in many cases.  Here's a nice article on the differences https://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2007/12/21/differences-between-unique-and-non-unique-indexes-part-ii/  it indicates for non-unique indexes multiple values could be found so the DB engine can't stop at first occurrence like it can in a unique index.  But again, that's only to be expected if you have data without unique indexes; as in any one to many relationship.